# Are these given formulas even correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{5x^2-4}}{x-7}$. Prove that $F(x)$ is the primitive of $f(x)=\frac{-35x+4}{(x-7)^2\sqrt{5x^2-4}}$.
>
> $G(x)=x^2(4x^2-2)^3+5$. Prove that $G(x)$ is the primitive of $g(x)=(32x^3-4x)(4x^2-2)^2$.

(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ566.jpg).)

I have got two functions, and I am supposed to solve them and show that they are eachothers primitive/derivative. I was told that it is possible that 1 of them is not correct and there is even a slight possibility that they are both incorrect.
I can't seem to figure it out, I tried to take the derivative of both primitives but it didn't work.

Comment: You can always use WolframAlpha to check whether the question is correct: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20x%5E2(4x%5E2-2)%5E3%2B5%20%3D%20(32x%5E3-4x)(4x%5E2-2)%5E2

Comment: I do not even understand what is there to solve. $F$ is primitive to $f$ if $F^\prime = f$, so prove it. Notice also that there is no "the" primitive, in the sense that any translation of a primitive function is also a primitive function.

Comment: @ErikJoensson Well I have to prove that one  F′= f in this case. 
I am sorry for "the" primitive, but you must understand that English isn't my native language, I can talk,listen and write English decently but especially with mathematical stuff I lack a certain amount of knowledge in words. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

$$(F(x)'=\left(\frac{\sqrt{5x^2-4}}{x-7}\right)'=\frac{(\sqrt{5x^2-4})'(x-7)-(x-7)'(\sqrt{5x^2-4})}{(x-7)^2}=f(x)$$